# Length of 2d parametric curve

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have seen a few other questions/answers with the same title, but with different equations.

I’d like to find a general solution to $\int\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt$

Specifically, I’d like to find the length of a 2D cubic Bézier segment expressed parametrically as $x=At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D$  and  $y=Et^3+Ft^2+Gt+H$

Clearly,$\frac{dx}{dt} = 3At^2+2Bt+C$ and  $\frac{dy}{dt} = 3Et^2+2Ft+G$  so for a Bézier segment, the integral would be $\int\sqrt{(3At^2+2Bt+C)^2+(3Et^2+2Ft+G)^2}dt$

That expands to the rather cumbersome $\int(\sqrt{9(A^{2}+E^2)t^4+12(AB+EF)ABt^3+(6(AC+EG)+4B^2+4F^2)t^2+4(BC+FG)t+C^2+G^2})dt$

Using the following substitutions:
$\alpha=9(A^{2}+E^2)$
$\beta=12(AB+EF)AB$
$\gamma=6(AC+EG)+4B^2+4F^2$
$\delta=4(BC+FG)$
$k=C^2+G^2$
the expression can be written as
$\int(\sqrt{\alpha t^4+\beta t^3+\gamma t^2+\delta t+k}) dt$
And that’s where I hit a brick wall. I have no idea how to proceed from here. I’ve been told that it will take an infinite series to express the solution, but I suspect that fewer than a dozen terms will be sufficient for computational accuracy.
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You are nice saying that you *hit a brick wall* ! For me, it is at least concrete or armored steel. I would be very surprised to know that there is a closed form. Think about numerical integration instead.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a closed form, and I would be happy with a series. This is for a computer program, and I already have a workable brute-force solution to the length problem that does not involve an integral, but depending on the parameters, it can result in adding fifty to a hundred or more terms. I'm hoping to find a solution that would give me a reasonable accurate answer in a dozen terms or fewer.

Comment: It would be a monster ! Moreover, the computations will be very expensive and you would not have any idea or control of the error.

Comment: If it were a convergent series, I could continue computing until a term had an absolute value less than about 10^-7 or so. The brute force method I am using now is at least very good about controlling the margin of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a numerical integration procedure, like [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). As usual, you can find easy-to-use (but often not-quite-optimal) code in the [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=179#) book.

There are Bézier curves for which you can compute the arclength exactly. They are called Pythagorean Hodograph (PH) curves, and have been studied extensively by [Rida Farouki](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540733973) and others. But, in return for easy arclength calculation, you sacrifice a lot of shape flexibility.

There is no closed-form formula for the arclength of a general Bézier curve whose degree is greater than 2.